# llvm clang installation fails

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am on CentOS 7.

I used SVN to download the sources. Clang version is 4.0 and LLVM is 3.9.0

After I run the "make" command, the "make install" gives the following error:

```
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangSerialization.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangFrontend.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangRewriteFrontend.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangFrontendTool.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangTooling.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangToolingCore.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangIndex.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libclangFormat.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/bin/clang-4.0
CMake Error at tools/clang/tools/driver/cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find "/home/user_dir/src/llvm/build/bin/clang".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  tools/clang/tools/cmake_install.cmake:38 (include)
  tools/clang/cmake_install.cmake:51 (include)
  tools/cmake_install.cmake:43 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)
```

It seems the make command can not build the clang executable. How to fix this?

I am following this "Getting started": http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Comment: Voting down without leaving a comment ?! What is wrong with my question ?!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Those sources  which are mentioned as optional are actually not! After I downloaded all of them through SVN and used "cmake build ." instead of "make" the clang executable were made and everything got compiled fully.

Comment: I am running into this issue as well. Can you please be more specific as to what other sources you had to build to be able to generate the clang, clang++ binaries?